# Calculating business days in Teradata

Tags: sql, teradata

I need help in business days calculation.

I've two tables

1) One table `ACTUAL_TABLE` containing order date and contact date with timestamp datatypes. 
2) The second table `BUSINESS_DATES` has each of the calendar dates listed and has a flag to indicate weekend days.

using these two tables, I need to ensure business days and not calendar days (which is the current logic) is calculated between these two fields.

My thought process was to first get a range of dates by comparing `ORDER_DATE` with `TABLE_DATE` field and then do a similar comparison of `CONTACT_DATE` to `TABLE_DATE` field. This would get me a range from the `BUSINESS_DATES` table which I can then use to calculate count of days, `sum(Holiday_WKND_Flag)` fields making the result look like:

```
Order#   | Count(*) As DAYS | SUM(WEEKEND DATES)
100      | 25               | 8
```

However this only works when I use a specific order number and cant' bring all order numbers in a sub query.

**My Query:**

```
SELECT SUM(Holiday_WKND_Flag), COUNT(*) FROM
(
SELECT 
* FROM 
BUSINESS_DATES
WHERE BUSINESS.Business  BETWEEN (SELECT ORDER_DATE FROM ACTUAL_TABLE
WHERE ORDER#  = '100'
)

AND

(SELECT CONTACT_DATE FROM ACTUAL_TABLE
WHERE ORDER# = '100'
)

TEMP
```

Uploading the table structure for your reference.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT      ORDER#, SUM(Holiday_WKND_Flag), COUNT(*) 
FROM        business_dates  bd
INNER JOIN  actual_table    at ON bd.table_date BETWEEN at.order_date AND at.contact_date
GROUP BY    ORDER#
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of joining on a BETWEEN (which always results in a bad Product Join) followed by a COUNT you better assign a *bussines day number* to each date (in best case this is calculated only once and added as a column to your calendar table). Then it's two Equi-Joins and no aggregation needed:

```
WITH cte AS
 (
   SELECT
      Cast(table_date AS DATE) AS table_date, 
      -- assign a consecutive number to each busines day, i.e. not increased during weekends, etc.
      Sum(CASE WHEN Holiday_WKND_Flag = 1 THEN 0 ELSE 1 end)
      Over (ORDER BY table_date
            ROWS Unbounded Preceding) AS business_day_nbr
   FROM business_dates
 )
SELECT ORDER#, 
   Cast(t.contact_date AS DATE) - Cast(t.order_date AS DATE) AS #_of_days
   b2.business_day_nbr - b1.business_day_nbr AS #_of_business_days
FROM actual_table AS t
JOIN cte AS b1
  ON Cast(t.order_date AS DATE) = b1.table_date
JOIN cte AS b2
  ON Cast(t.contact_date AS DATE) = b2.table_date
```

Btw, why are `table_date` and `order_date` `timestamp` instead of a `date`?
Porting from Oracle?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this query. Hope it helps

```
select order#, 
    order_date, 
    contact_date, 
    (select count(1) 
            from business_dates_table 
            where table_date between a.order_date and a.contact_date 
                  and holiday_wknd_flag = 0
    ) business_days 
from actual_table a
```