# Teradata - last three business day transactions ( that accounts for weekend and public holidays)

Tags: sql, teradata, teradatasql

There is a transaction table tran_details that has a transaction date and there is calender table calender_days that has flag against all dates if a particular day is a business day or not.  I have few hundreds scoped members and transactions eg. Account_No abc TranDate 14/06/2022 (Tuesday). Now I want all transaction on that account for last three business days and if 13/06/22 was a public holiday and 11/06/22 and 12/06.22 was a weekend, transactions from  09/06/2022 to 14/06/2022 which would mean 3 business days - 09/06, 10/06 and 14/06. I want logic that can calculate how many days to go back in every case to reach up till 3 business days considering public holidays and weekends.

Comment: Do you wantt the same three business daate for all members or individually per member based on their last transaction? Are there any transaction on non-business days?

Comment: You could build a view or derived table in your query that excludes all non-business days from your date table, and then use row_number to derive a sequence number. Then identifying the last 3 business days should be simple.

Comment: Hi @dnoeth  Yes, I want individual last three business days transactions based on customer's last transaction. Yes there can be transactions on non business days, so best to go with anything between 9th June to 14th June from my example.

Answer (score 1):

Derive a business day number from your calendar, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/43040273/2527905 in a Derived Table and join to it.

And then apply a

```
QUALIFY
   TranDate between max(businessday#) over (partition by Account_No) -2
                and max(businessday#) over (partition by Account_No)
```